# Why is there a condition on L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is the presence of an indeterminate form necessary for L'Hopital's rule to work? Why can't it work on functions not containing an indeterminate form? Is there an intuitive way to understand why this happens?

Comment: Surely you would agree that $\lim_{x\to 0}x / (x^2+1)=0$. However, if we blindly apply LHR to it, we get $\lim_{x\to 0} 1/(2x)$, which doesn't exist. In math, you have to 'read the user agreement' before you apply theorems.

Comment: A while back, 3blue1brown posted a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfF40MiS7zA) that seeks to explain why L'Hôpital's rule works intuitively. The video focuses on $0/0$—perhaps others can explain why L'Hôpital's rule works in the case of $\infty/\infty$. Also, I think it is helpful to shift one's mindset. By default, *don't* expect something to work until it has been proven otherwise.

Comment: You might also want to check the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Proof_of_L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule). Hint: the $0/0$ situation allows as to alter the fraction into a derivative form

Comment: @Integrand Aren't we able to repeat L'Hospital as much as necessary per "the user agreement", giving, in your example $\lim_{x\to 0} 0/2$ ?

Comment: @e2-e4 why not apply LHR fifty times then and get $\lim_{x\to 0}0/0$?

Comment: @Integrand Because it's not in the "[user agreement](https://www.quora.com/Can-LHospital%E2%80%99s-rule-be-applied-more-than-once#:~:text=Hey-,Yes%20L'Hospital's%20rule%20can%20be%20applied%20more%20than%20once,it's%20not%20of%20the%20form)" :-)

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Did you think about the proof of l'Hopital's rule? And did you think about counterexamples when the hypothesis is not assumed? And is there something about the proof or those counterexamples you don't understand? Generally speaking, if you want to know why a certain hypothesis is present in a theorem, there are two ways that you can proceed. First, read the proof to see how the hypothesis is used (see the answer of @B.Goddard). Second, try to find counterexamples when the hypothesis is not assumed (see the previous comments).

Comment: @Integrand but what if we apply LH rule again on 1/2x to get 0/2=0  ?

Comment: @e2-e4 you can adapt my example to something even more confusing. For instance, look at $\lim_{x\to 0}(x^4-3 x^3-2 x^2+x)/(2 x^4-x^3-x^2+x+1)$. The limit as $x\to 0$ is zero; however, if you mistakenly apply LHR 1,2,3,4 times, you get $\{1,2,3,1/2\}$, respectively. What to make of all of this? You *cannot* invoke a theorem *unless* its prerequisites are satsified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

L'hospital comes from linear approximation.

$$f(x+h) \approx f(x) + f^{\prime}(x)h. $$

So for a limit of the ratio of two functions you should have

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x) + f^{\prime}(x)h}{g(x) + g^{\prime}(x)h}.  $$

See that if $f(x) = g(x) = 0$  (the condition you're asking about) then the above is

$$= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)h}{ g^{\prime}(x)h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{ g^{\prime}(x)}.$$

If you don't have the condition, the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$  don't disappear and you can't conclude the last expression.

Comment: Since $f(x+h)$ is only approximately equal to $f(x)+f'(x)h$, how can we formally justify the replacement of $f(x+h)$ with $f(x)+f'(x)h$? I understand that as $h$ gets smaller and smaller, the approximation gets better and better, but I'm not sure how to turn this into a rigorous argument.

Comment: @Joe  A calc text would give a rigorous argument, but the OP wanted intuition.   Basically, the definition of "differentiable" means that the error in the approximation is much smaller than $h$, so the substitution works.